# How to delete a record from a text file?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, record, delete-record

How do you delete a record (that is in array struct) from a text file? My code works but it deletes other records too. May I know whats wrong with my code? Here's what it looks like:

```
{           
    zfp = fopen("note.txt", "wb+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
          printf("| File can not be opened.\n");
          exit(1);
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        if(k == s)
        {
            strcpy(notes[s].title, "\0");
            notes[s].day = 0;
            notes[s].month = 0;
            notes[s].year = 0;
        }
    }
    fwrite(&note, sizeof(note), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

By the way, before that part, I have a code that asks for the event number that you want to delete. The array index starts at 0 and the event number starts at 1. So the data/record associated with that event number would be `s = eventnumber - 1` to match with the index of the arrays.

Comment: Using `fwrite` and `struct` and 'text file' together, isn't the way to go.

Comment: Read the file. Modify the data in memory. Write the data to a new file. Delete the old file. Rename the new file to the old file name. Use full paths to the files to be sure it is affecting the files you want it to.

Comment: You're writing a binary file, not a text file.

Comment: What is `note`? Your loop processes an array called `notes.

Comment: There's no need to use a loop and `if` statement to zero out one record of an array. Just do the assignments to `notes[s]` without a loop.

Comment: regarding: `printf("| File can not be opened.\n");`   this does not tell the user enough information to fix the problem.  suggest:  `perror( "fopen to read note.txt failed");`  will output both your error message AND the reason the OS thinks the call to `fopen()` failed to `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

Write the records one at a time rather than writing the whole array. Then you can simply skip the one that you want to delete.

```
{           
    zfp = fopen("note.txt", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
          printf("| File can not be opened.\n");
          exit(1);
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        if(k != s)
        {
            write(&notes[k], sizeof(notes[k]), 1, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```